# python pandas: manually write to the same Excel after exporting a dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I export a dataframe to Excel this way:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame( data= np.ones((4,2)), columns=['x','y'])

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
sheet='Test'
df.to_excel(writer,sheet)

writer.save()
```

How can I get python to write a few lines of description to the right of the dataframe? Something like: "this dataframe contains bla bla bla".
Specifically:

1. Can I use pandas to write to the same sheet? Or do I have to use
   another module after `writer.save()`? Saving and reopening seems like
   a waste of time and resources
2. If I cannot use pandas, what
   module shall I use? xlsxwriter cannot modify existing file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the XlsxWriter workbook/worksheet before saving and do any modifications you want there.  E.g.

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet)
wb = writer.book
ws = writer.sheets[sheet]
ws.write(1, 4, "DataFrame contains ...")
writer.save()
```